# How to have dynamic scene update in libqglviewer

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using libqglviewer for a project, I read input from a motion capture device through USB and display this as a human in the viewer.  I draw the opengl things in the draw() method of the viewer, it works fine.  However, when the motion controllers change, I actually get new position values and i draw these in the viewer, BUT i dont see this update until i click on the viewer screen.  Is it possible to update the frames in the viewer by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to post an `updateGL` right after you get the new position values.

[QGLWidget::updateGL()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qglwidget.html#updateGL)

```
    void QGLWidget::updateGL () [virtual slot]
    Updates the widget by calling glDraw().
```

For painting in 2D the function is called `update`.

Also, don't call it from inside your draw method (see [updateGL](http://www.libqglviewer.com/refManual/classQGLViewer.html#ae12b7378efbffabc24a133ca1deb19ae) in the libQGLViewer documentation).

This note comes from [QWidget::paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#paintEvent):

Note: Generally, you should refrain from calling update() or repaint() inside a paintEvent(). For example, calling update() or repaint() on children inside a paintevent() results in undefined behavior; the child may or may not get a paint event.

The same probably applies for QGLViewer.

You can also use `repaint`, but is isn't recommended (see [QWidget::repaint()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#repaint)).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I will try it and let you know!